# Merging multiple json arrays in the same file

Tags: bash, jq

I'm currently downloading a ton of jira issues to generate a report. Currently the 'full data' file has a ton of individual records like this:

```
{
    "key": "645",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Crash when saving document",
    "closedDate": "2014-10-03T09:01:23.000+0200",
    "flag": null,
    "fixVersionID": "123",
    "fixVersionName": "2.7"
}
```

However, because I'm downloading multiple versions and appending to the same file I end up with this kind of structure.

```
[
  {
    "key": "645",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Crash when saving document",
    "closedDate": "2014-10-03T09:01:23.000+0200",
    "flag": null,
    "fixVersionID": "123",
    "fixVersionName": "2.7"
  }
]
[
  {
    "key": "552",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Graphical Issue",
    "closedDate": "2014-10-13T09:01:23.000+0200",
    "flag": null,
    "fixVersionID": "456",
    "fixVersionName": "2.8"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is to count the number of records with a specific date and then doing the same looping through a starting date to an end date using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

But, I can't figure out how to:

1. Flatten the records so that they are one array not two
2. Strip the `T09:01:23.000+0200` from the closedDate value
3. Count the number of objects with a specific date value such as `2014-10-13`

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to strip `T09:01:23.000+0200`. when you map the jira issue do: `map({closedDate: .fields.resolutiondate[0:10]})` that'll give you just the first ten characters.

Comment: `grep '2014-10-13' some.json | wc -l` will it not be enough to get the count?

Comment: @pratZ it will, but I wanted a slightly cleaner solution. I know that jq has a max and a min function and was looking for something similar. But if grep does it, then so be it. The real issue is the flattening of the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple independent inputs. To be able to combine them in any meaningful way, you'll have to slurp up the input. The inputs will be treated as an array of the inputs. Then you could combine them into a single array by `add`ing them.

Since the dates are all in a certain fixed format, you can take substrings of the dates.

```
"2014-10-13T09:01:23.000+0200"[:10] -> "2014-10-13"
```

Given that, you can then filter by the date you want and count using the `length` filter.

```
add | map(select(.closedDate[:10]=="2014-10-13")) | length
```

e.g.,

```
$ cat input.json
[
  {
    "key": "645",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Crash when saving document",
    "closedDate": "2014-10-03T09:01:23.000+0200",
    "flag": null,
    "fixVersionID": "123",
    "fixVersionName": "2.7"
  }
]
[
  {
    "key": "552",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "1",
    "status": "Closed",
    "summary": "Graphical Issue",
    "closedDate": "2014-10-13T09:01:23.000+0200",
    "flag": null,
    "fixVersionID": "456",
    "fixVersionName": "2.8"
  }
]
$ jq -s 'add | map(select(.closedDate[:10]=="2014-10-13")) | length' input.json
1
```

Comment: Meh, insert desired method of input as needed. For a file, yes, useless, but I have no idea what the actual source is, but whatever it is, it probably can be piped in.

Comment: @JeffMercado source of input is a curl call to jira which has an upper limit on the number of objects retrieved. So I have to do sequential calls and write them to a file. I wish I knew why that was useless though. It seems useful to me!

Comment: @TheMightyLlama: Search "UUOC". The idea is that using `cat` to pipe to another process is a useless, inefficient use of `cat. It's better to redirect instead or use some other form of input. Personally I find no problem with its use.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 and 2:

```
$ echo -e "[\n$(sed '/^[][]$/d;/closedDate/s/\(T[^"]*\)//g' json)\n]" > flat-json
```

To count the number for special day:

```
$ grep "closedDate" flat-json | grep "2014-10-13" | wc -l
```